# Some test cases are failing. Tell me what went wrong

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

Given the names and grades for each student in a Physics class of  students, store them in a nested list and print the name(s) of any student(s) having the second lowest grade.

Note: If there are multiple students with the same grade, order their names alphabetically and print each name on a new line.

Input Format

The first line contains an integer, , the number of students.
The  subsequent lines describe each student over  lines; the first line contains a student's name, and the second line contains their grade.

Constraints

There will always be one or more students having the second lowest grade.
Output Format

Print the name(s) of any student(s) having the second lowest grade in Physics; if there are multiple students, order their names alphabetically and print each one on a new line.

Sample Input 0

5
Harry
37.21
Berry
37.21
Tina
37.2
Akriti
41
Harsh
39
Sample Output 0

Berry
Harry
Explanation 0

There are  students in this class whose names and grades are assembled to build the following list:

python students = [['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Tina', 37.2], ['Akriti', 41], ['Harsh', 39]]

The lowest grade of  belongs to Tina. The second lowest grade of  belongs to both Harry and Berry, so we order their names alphabetically and print each name on a new line.

my code:
**

```
marksheet=[]
for _ in range(int(raw_input())):
    stud=[]
    name = raw_input()
    score = float(raw_input())
    stud.append(name)
    stud.append(score)
    marksheet.append(stud)
marksheet.sort(key= lambda x:x[0])
minimum = min(marksheet,key = lambda x:x[1])
for x in marksheet:
    if x[1]== minimum[1]:
        marksheet.remove(x)
sec_high=min(marksheet, key= lambda x :x[1]  )
for x in marksheet:
    if x[1] == sec_high[1]:
        print x[0]
```

**

Comment: For a start why don't you do `marksheet.append((name, score))` you don't need to construct a stud list. Further for _ in range(int(raw_input()) seems wrong, does that even work? Most probably you will get a ValueError.

Comment: it is python 2.7, the for loop works just fine. 8 out of 10 test cases are working.
question link : https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/nested-list/problem

Comment: As a beginner why are you working with python 2.7? It will become unsupported and obsolete in 4 months. I strongly advice to move to python 3.7

Comment: Sure sir, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution (Tested on Hackerank)

```
# Gather Inputs
n = int(raw_input())
lst = []
for x in range(n):
    lst.append([raw_input(), float(raw_input())])

# Sort by score (i.e. sublists are [name, score])
lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[1])

# Find second lowest score
for x in range(1, n):
    if(lst[x][1] != lst[x-1][1]):
        score = lst[x][1]
        break

#Sort by name
lst = sorted(lst)

# Aggregate students whose result was score
# this is the second lowest value
lower_scorers = [x[0] for x in lst if x[1] == score]

print "\n".join(lower_scorers)
```

**Test**

*Input*

```
5
Harry
37.21
Berry
37.21
Tina
37.2
Akriti
41
Harsh
39
```

*Output*

```
Berry
Harry
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this solution in Python 3.7 ...

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    mark_sheet = []
    _min = 1e99
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        if score < _min:
            _min = score
        mark_sheet.append((name, score))

    # make a new mark_sheet excluding the one(s) that have the minimum score and 
    # sort on score in ascending order
    mark_sheet = sorted([mark for mark in mark_sheet if mark[1] != _min], key=lambda x: x[1])

    # if there is still a list then the first item should have the second best score
    mark_second_best = []
    if mark_sheet:
        second_best_score = mark_sheet[0][1]

        # make a list with the second best score and sort on name
        mark_second_best = sorted([mark for mark in mark_sheet if mark[1] == second_best_score],
            key=lambda x: x[0])

    # and print the result
    for mark in mark_second_best:
        print(mark[0])
```

passed HackerRank.